# prototype.onClick firing 3 times on double-click

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser

I've inherited some JavaScript code that implements a soft keyboard with a custom `Keyboard` class with several `prototype` methods - both custom methods and methods that seem to be overrides of some defaults. (First confession is that I'm not very experienced with JavaScript, and have only skimmed a few references to the `prototype` approach.)

The `prototype` methods are defined like this, and this is the specific method not doing what I expect:

```
Keyboard.prototype.onClick = function(keyImageElement) {
    keyImageElement = window.event.srcElement;
    var keyboard = keyImageElement.keyboard;

    // Make sure that the srcElement is a key image element
    if (keyboard !== undefined) {
        if (!keyImageElement.disabled)
        {
            Keyboard.setOpacity(keyImageElement, .70);
            var resetFilter = function() {
                Keyboard.setOpacity(keyImageElement, 1);
            };
            setTimeout(resetFilter, 200);

            keyboard.updateInputField(keyImageElement.name);
        }
    }
};
```

(Yes, I know this is using IE-specific mechanisms; it's for an IE-based embedded browser. However, I've also duplicated the same behavior passing `e` and using `e.target` in Firefox.)

Keyboard creates a DOM `div`, and appends to it a DOM `span` element for each key, of which there are a couple dozen.

In IE 7 and 8 modes, this works correctly. No matter how fast I click, I only get one event per click. But in IE >=9, and in Firefox 48, if I click twice, fast enough (presumably to register as a double-click, but it doesn't actually have to be super fast), I get 3 events, not 2.

I've tried the `event` `stopPropagation()`, `preventDefault()`, and `stopImmediatePropagation()` methods, but those haven't changed the behavior.

I'm guessing some underlying browser/JavaScript/standards changes are responsible for this different behavior, but I don't know what specifically, or how to address it.

Among other things, I don't seem to be able to similarly override some other `onXxx()` event methods. In fact, the original code has `Keyboard.prototype.onMouseDown()` and `onMouseUp()` methods, for instance, but it turns out those are not being triggered at all, even in the older IE modes.

**Edit**: Since it's clear that even double-clicks call `onClick()`, I've tried using the `detail` element to determine which case this is, and ignore the "extra" call for the double-click, but it turns out:

1. Firefox sees a count of 1, 2, 2. I was expecting and counting on 1, 1, 2
2. IE doesn't seem to support this at all, seeing 0, 0, 0

Comment: Meta: I'm also interested in any thoughts on why I'm not finding any examples of doing event handling with `prototype` methods like this.

Comment: BTW, it was only in IE 11 Edge mode that the detail values were zero. Which seems like a bug. In 9 and 10 modes, they were 1,2,2. In 7 or 8 modes, that property doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've addressed my immediate issue. I can check the [`type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) field for 'click' vs. 'dblclick'.

NOTE:

- IE >=9 (and Firefox) sends click, click, dblclick
- IE < 9 sends click, dblclick

(Still would love to see a good reference on using prototype methods to override event handling.)